# revert multiple branch merged to develop

Tags: git, merge, branch, git-branch, git-revert

So I have a branch named `BRANCH_A` and there is another branch named `BRANCH_B` which these two branchs merged to develop branch. Now something went wrong in `BRANCH_A`, it's looks like regression for some reasons, maybe bad merged, after this merge I had few minor commits also in `BRANCH_A` anyway I need to revert back `BRANCH_A` to a safe commit before this merged happened. I follow other similar issues posts in stack, and did this as below :

first inside `BRANCH_A` I create a backup branch :

```
git branch BACKUP_A
```

Then reset to SHA from yesterday, which is a commit just before that merged happened :

```
git reset --hard SHA
```

Then point the `BRANCH_A` to backup branch :

```
git reset --soft BACKUP_A
```

Then commit :

```
git commit -m "Revert to SHA id"
```

and pushed :

```
git push
```

This will revert to that commit, But the thing is, I still have other branch changes ( for BRANCH_B ) on that merge  and this only revert back those minor commits that I did after merge.

How can I revert in a way that I get raid of those changes from other Branch ( BRANCH_B ) and only keep changes that I actually did in BRANCH_A ( the commit before merge ) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to fix this issue by doing these :

Inside the branch_a that have issue :

```
Git reset —hard commitID
Git merge origin/develop
Git push -f
```

Then checkout develop and delete the branch_a

```
git checkout develop
git branch D branch_a
```

And checkout it again

```
git checkout branch_a
```

Hope it works for someone who face similar issue.

**Note : Be careful when you run `Git push -f`  because if you made a mistake you will loose your code**